# Use algebra to calculate the perimeter of a right angle triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Use algebra to calculate the perimeter of a right angle triangle where the hypotenuse is $(x+4)$, the base is $(x+3)$ and the remaining side is $(x-4)$.

Thanks to the earlier comments I know that I need to use Pythagoras.

So far I know that the Theorem says that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

I can write my problem as $(x-4)^2 + (x+3)^2 = (x+4)^2$

What should I do next?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Pythagorean Theorem? What is your work so far?

Comment: Pythagorean Theorem is a^2 + b^2 = c^2?

Comment: I had started by expanding the brackets to try and find x but I think this is the wrong direction entirely

Comment: Have you applied the Pythagorean Theorem? Sounds like you know what it is. Please post your work.

Comment: a^2 + b^2 = c^2             (x-4)^2 + (x+3)^2 = (x+4)^2

Comment: This is my first time here, is it best to post my work in the comments or along with the original question?

Comment: @Moose I've put your work in the question - a question that shows some effort from the questioner is less likely to be closed.

Comment: Now expand those brackets and simplify the equation - you should get a straightforward quadratic equation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done.
$$\begin{align*}(x - 4)^2 + (x + 3)^2 &= (x + 4)^2 \\
\implies x^2 - 8x + 16 + x^2 + 6x + 9 &= x^2 + 8x + 16 \\
\implies x^2 - 10x + 9&= 0 \\
\implies (x - 9)(x - 1) &= 0 \end{align*}$$
So either $x = 9$ or $x = 1$. We know $x \neq 1$ because that would make a side of the triangle $x - 4 = -3$ which is negative. Hence $x = 9$.

Now the perimeter is $(x + 4) + (x + 3) + (x - 4) = 13 + 12 + 5 = 30$.

Comment: Many thanks everyone, I understand now. I will be sure to add all my work to future questions. :)